# More options for page--node--edit.html.twig for content type

Tags: 8, theming

Using my Theme debug I'm getting the following themplate suggestions

```
page--node--blogpost.html.twig

page--node--edit.html.twig
```

When I tried to use different template to edit a blogpost template only like

```
page--node--edit--blogpost.html.twig
```

the template was ignored. How to add more template suggestion for Drupal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called **theme suggestions** you can implement [your own or alter existing ones](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter/8.8.x). In this case since the *theme* hook is provided by another module (core) you need to alter the provided suggestions and add your own.

Check [this post](https://www.chapterthree.com/blog/how-to-create-custom-theme-suggestions-drupal-8) with useful examples. Also core's always have excelent examples (Bartik theme example).

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter() for form templates.
 */
function bartik_theme_suggestions_form_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {
  if ($variables['element']['#form_id'] == 'search_block_form') {
    $suggestions[] = 'form__search_block_form';
  }
}
```